# Python Program using List

Tags: python, list

Accept `N` numbers in the list `L`. Shift the first half element to second half and second half elements to first half. Eg. `L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` after shifting `L = [4,5,6,1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

If `L` is a list of length `N`:

```py
L = L[N // 2:] + L[:N // 2]
```

will switch the first and second halves of the list.